# How can i use my SQL based database software from a remote area with the help of internet

Tags: sql-server

How can i use my SQL based database software from a remote area with the help of internet.

I m using a Sql based database software in my head office to maintain our material flow, like receiving, issue and some other things.

Our site office is also doing the same thing.

So, is it possible to give our site office access to my Software using internet?

So that everyone can use the same and one software.

W. Hasan

Comment: It might be worth asking the people who wrote the software how it talks to the database; some sql server applications (generally bad ones) are network intensive rather than server intensive. If you wrote it internally then depending on how you connect to the DB aaron's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to grant the remote users access from their network.

```
GRANT [ACTIONS] ON [db_name].[table_name] TO '[remote_user_name]'@'[ip_address]';
```

You can add a wildcard to any of those to make it more general. For example:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON employees.* TO 'hr_user'@'123.456.*';
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think your software should need changes.
Implement remoting so that others have software an update or access Databse through remoting.